# Binary file that can be read by both, Mathematica and Python

Tags: export, import, python

I would like to analyze data set in both Matematica and Python. What is a time and size efficient format to store the data?

Comment: Take a look at [WXF](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/WXF.html). The format description is [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WXFFormatDescription.html). It can be read by WL / Mathematica using `BinaryDeserialize` and created from WL using `BinarySerialize`, while on the python side the serializer and deserializer are implemented in [Wolfram Client for Python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/). This is a fast and efficient binary format.

Comment: **To the closers**: to me this seems a perfectly legitimate question. I don't understand the reason for close votes here.

Comment: You should elaborate on what kind of binary data it is as this may have some bearing on the best choice of format. Is it audio, images, sparse, compressed, or completely arbitrary? What overall volume of data and whether the data is delivered in small or big chunks.

Comment: The file is a big chunk of data. It's imported into Mathematica using: Import[file <> ".bin", "Real32"]. I want to to export it as to be able to read it in python using NumPy or Pandas.

Comment: "big chunk of data" - yes but I was more asking: what does it represent? Anyway if it's a load of 32-bit floats then technically you could just save each 4-byte value one after another in a binary file and unpack in python using the struct module. But then if you want something flexible with more features if a bit heavyweight, you could use [HDF5](https://www.h5py.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way that I've been using is:

```
data.astype('uint16').tofile('C:\\path\\file.dat')
```

in Python, and

```
data = BinaryReadList["C:\\path\\file.dat", "UnsignedInteger16"]
```

in Mathematica. I believe the reverse can work as well using `BinaryWriteList` in Mathematica.

You can evaluate Python code directly in the Mathematica front end as well. This probably isn't as convenient for large programs, but something like:

```
mylist = Range[10]

> import numpy as np
  arr = np.array(<* mylist *>)
  arr.sum()
```

returns 55. To enter Python mode inside Mathematica, you type the > character at the beginning of the cell.